# Condition Expressions in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a test dynamodb table described thusly:

```
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "p_key",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "s_key",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "test_table",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "p_key",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "s_key",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": 1582577061.111,
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 0,
        "ItemCount": 0,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:XXXXXX:table/test_table",
        "TableId": "e5a518fc-4411-4218-b7ff-XXXXXX"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to accomplish a put_item request and testing against the presence of another, non-index value. In the table described above, let's say I have the item:

```
    "Items": [
        {
            "p_key": {
                "S": "test"
            },
            "s_key": {
                "S": "0"
            },
            "test_value": {
                "N": "123"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 1,
    "ScannedCount": 1,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

I want to create a new item with a new sort key (s_key) only if it doesn't an already existing value in the database. So I've tried the following:

```
aws dynamodb put-item \
    --item '{"p_key": {"S":"test"}, "s_key": {"S": "1"}, "test_value":{"N":"123"}}' \
    --table-name test_table \
    --condition-expression "#tv <> :v" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":v":{"N":"123"}}' \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#tv":"test_value"}'
```

But the condition doesn't appear to match and the record gets written. Similar tests but against the sort or hash keep seem to effectively prevent the write.

Could someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: For clarity, are you saying you only want to create a record if there isn't already another record with a specific value that is not part of the key?

Comment: yes, so I'd like to *fail* the creation of a new record:
p_key: "test", s_key: "2", test_value: "123" because test_value already matches an existing record.

Comment: That won't work. You can't do conditions that require you to evaluate other records in the table. If the value is part of the key (partition or sort) you can effectively achieve this because the you would be updating the record matching the value you are specifying (because it's part of the key).

Comment: Based on the behavior that's what it seemed like, but looking through the docs I didn't find anything that suggested non-key values weren't usable for this case.

Comment: You can do conditions on non-key values, but they condition only applies to the record you are updating/putting. For example, you can say only update the record if it has a version of X, even if version isn't part of the key. You just can't use it to look at other records.

Comment: So in the above case, can you help explain what's happening?  I'm explicitly setting the value in the put-item request for the value which I'm sayin cannot exist. Shouldn't this action itself fail because test_value = 123, and I'm saying "test_value <> 123"?

Comment: It's looking at the value *before* you set it. So unless there is already a record with that key in the table, and the value for `test_value` is already 123, it will succeed.